# Monitoring unhealthy hosts on google cloud

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am using an external monitoring service (not stackdriver)
I wish to monitor the number of unhealthy hosts on my load balancer.
It seems like the google cloud api doesn't expose this metrics
therefore I implemented a custom script that gets the instance groups of the load balancer, get the instances' data (dns) and performs the health check
pretty cumbersome. is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command '[gcloud compute backend-services get-health](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/backend-services/get-health)' to get the status of each instance in your backend service. This command will provide the current status of each instance, HEALTHY or UNHEALTHY, that is part of your backend service.